# Description label normal but value in bold

Tags: enumitem, description

I want to create something like:

Name:     **Myname**

Address:  **MyAddress**

How can I do that? Currently I have done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{description}[noitemsep, font=\normalfont, labelwidth=5cm]
\item[Name:]  \textbf{MyAddress}
\item[Address:] \textbf{Myaddress}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

But I want not to write always the bold code. I'm using enumitem.

Comment: What about `\bfseries` enclosed around the `description` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \begin{document}
    \bfseries{\begin{itemize}[font=\normalfont]
     \item[Name:] Myname
     \item[Address:] Myaddress
     \item[Label 3:] Item 3
    \end{itemize}}
    \end{document}
```

[image]